# Nested do loop in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to generate 100 samples of 25 observations each of pseudonormal random variables using the rannor function. So here, 100= # of samples, and 25=sample size.

```
%macro bootstrap(bootsample, sample, samplesize);
  data &bootsample;
  %do i=1 %to &sample;
     do j=1 to &samplesize;
     obsnumber=ceil(&samplesize*rannor(642014));
     output;
     end;
     proc univariate data=&bootsample normal;
     ods output TestsForNormality=tests;
     var obsnumber;
     histogram obsnumber;
     run;
   %end;
   run;
   %mend;

%bootstrap(bootsample,100,25);
```

But I keep on receiving the error:  Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Just move the first %do

```
%macro bootstrap(bootsample, sample, samplesize);
      %do i=1 %to &sample;
      data &bootsample;
         do j=1 to &samplesize;
         obsnumber=ceil(&samplesize*rannor(642014));
         output;
         end;
         proc univariate data=&bootsample normal;
         ods output TestsForNormality=tests;
         var obsnumber;
         histogram obsnumber;
         run;
       %end;
       run;
       %mend;

       %bootstrap(bootsample,100,25);
```

or

```
%MACRO BOOTSTRAP(SAMPLES=,SIZE=);
data NormalBootstrap;
    do sample=1 to &SAMPLES;
        do size=1 to &SIZE;
            value=rannor(642014);
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;
%MEND;
%BOOTSTRAP(SAMPLES=100,SIZE=25);
 proc univariate data=NormalBootstrap normal;
         ods output TestsForNormality=tests;
         var value;
         by sample;
         histogram value;
run;
```

(I do not have sas graph so I submitted the code above without the histogram statement)

Comment: #2 is the correct answer.  #1 is very much slower and harder to code/maintain.  A macro is not needed at all - it's fine if you want it (as it's presented in the second option) or prefer it for organizational purposes but if this isn't something you are going to reuse it isn't necessary.